# Can I use a query annotation in mongo db/spring data to match a set member that is a dbref

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm using spring data and have an account collection which has a collection of users and a deleted flag and other attributes.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55f1f6222dcfdf26278d3c0a"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "users" : [
            DBRef("users", ObjectId("55f4f6222dcfdf26278d3c07"))
    ],
    "modules: [
            DBRef("modules", ObjectId("55f4f6232dcfdf26278d3c07"))
    ],
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to query for accounts by user.  I can do a derived query (documented here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries ):

```
Account findByUsersAndDeleted(User user, boolean deleted);
```

in my dao class which extends `MongoRepository`.

All well and good.  But I'd really like to be able to add a second method in which `deleted` defaults to false, to give me the non deleted accounts only.  I'd prefer to do this with an annotation (as opposed to writing a query in java using `MongoTemplate` http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template )

Unfortunately,

```
@Query("{deleted:false, 'user.$id' : ?0}")
Account findByUsers(User user);
```

Neither does:

```
@Query("{deleted:false, 'user' : ?0}")
Account findByUsers(User user);
```

I think the issue is either that `Users` is a set or that `Users` is an object stored as a dbref, or a combination.  If I search by an id field, rather than an object, it works fine:

```
@Query("{deleted:false, 'modules.$id' : ?0}")
Account findByModules(String id);
```

Is there a way to have `User` dereferenced to an id?  Or any other approach that might work to keep the query in an annotation?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for a way to have an DBRef-object argument in query method, then try using SpEL:

```
@Query("{deleted:false, 'users.$id' : ?#{[0].id} }")
Account findByUsers(User user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Account findByUsersAndDeletedIsFalse(User user);
```

instead. At least in SpringData Mongo shipped with Spring 4.3. And of course you can change call of your method to findByUsers(user.id) and use @Query like you show for "modules"

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I unfortunately can't accept it because I'm not able to access the codebase and verify it, but appreciate your time.